# Jquery .addClass('myclass') Then Selecting 'myclass' Isn't Working

Tags: jquery

I've got a couple divs with the class "listingThumb"

the CSS:

```
.listingThumb{
height:50px;
width:50px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

the Html:

```
<div class="listingThumb"><img src="mypic.jpg"></div>
```

I want a user to be able to click that div and add a border that I have in another class that I add with .addClass()

```
.selectedThumb{
border:1px #f00 solid;
}
```

With this function:

```
$('.listingThumb').live('click',
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('selectedThumb');
    }
);
```

That all works fine and dandy.  My problem is that I want the selected div to switch when a user clicks another div.  So, what I do with my function is this...

```
$('.listingThumb').live('click',
    function(){
        $('.listingThumb').removeClass('selectedThumb'); // <-- remove any instance of that class...
        $(this).addClass('selectedThumb');
    }
);
```

But, any div that I've added 'selectedThumb' to via jquery doesn't register as having that class as it was added dynamically.

Is there a common solution for this?

Thanks
-J

Comment: This should work. Not sure why it wouldn't. It doesn't matter that the class was added dynamically. Running your code, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Nhw6R/1/

Comment: @patrick... I used your first answer and it worked!  please add it back so I can give you your credit.

Comment: @Alex... Maybe I fixed a syntax error writing it out here.. anyhow I changed it to patrick's original solution and am having success.

Comment: @Jascha - If that worked, then there's some other issue. I'll bring it back, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try selecting specifically on the class you're removing:

```
$('.listingThumb').live('click',
    function(){
        $('.selectedThumb').removeClass('selectedThumb'); 
        $(this).addClass('selectedThumb');
    }
);
```

Although it really shouldn't make a difference. If you're having issues when selecting via `listingThumb`, I'd check spelling/capitalization first.

Comment: I swear it is making a difference... using FF 3.6.12... I've switched it back and forth twice.

Comment: @Jascha - I believe you, but there's something strange going on. Unless there's some code that removes the `listingThumb` class when you add the `selectedThumb` class, it should work perfectly to select using the original class. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for 'selectedThumb', why not search for it?

```
$('.selectedThumb').removeClass('selectedThumb');
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with what you've provided...

See here for it working in jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BPND5/)

Comment: upvote for awesome site link... I swear it's not working for me.  It's likely some other issue, I've switched my selector up ala Patrick's suggestion and am having success... gonna leave it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, though this would make sure any element with that class would be removed:

```
$('.listingThumb').live('click',
    function(){
        $('.selectedThumb').removeClass('selectedThumb'); // <-- remove any instance of that class...
        $(this).addClass('selectedThumb');

    }
);
```